# Displaying GridValueLayer styles in Repast Simphony 2.3.1?

Tags: java, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

Repast Simphony 2.0-beta had a known [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/repast/mailman/message/27491795/) with specifying value layer styles.

The option to display them did not show up in the GUI interface.
In the GUI, right-clicking on a display and selecting 'Edit', should open a window several tabs along the left side:

- General
- Agent Selection
- Agent Style
- Grid Style
- **Value Layer Details** and
- Schedule Details

With the bug, the "**Value Layer Details**" tab does not show up, so it is not possible to set the ValueLayer Style and see the state of the layer.

Is that bug fixed by default in version 2.3.1? **I am having a similar problem. The tab does not show up**.

[image]

My question is is this the same problem or something else and how do I fix it?

## Solution to the original problem

The problem was fixed by downloading three .class files, Nick Collier attached to an email on the Repast mailing list, to the folder:

Repast-Simphony-2.0.0-beta/eclipse/plugins/repast.simphony.visualization_2.0.0/bin/repast/simphony/visualization/gui

## An example where it works

Repast StupidModel, which was hosted on Google Code, has an example where the option shows up. That model was built with an earlier version of Repast. I have tried to replicate their implementation of the ValueLayer and style sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is fixed.

Adding this line to the file context.xml makes the option show up in the GUI:

```
<projection id="foodValueLayer" type="value layer" />
```